# How do I populate a table with values from a dropdown box?

Tags: php, post

I have three tables and two dropdown boxes. I have populated two of the tables and entered their values into the dropdown boxes. Now, I would like to choose a value from both of the dropdown boxes and put their values into the third dropdown box.

```
    <fieldset>
            <legend>New Cast</legend>
            <table>
            <form action="04castdb.php" method="post">
            </fieldset>
<?php

$query = "select * from dbhx_movie";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
{
    die("query failed");
}
    echo "<select name='movie'>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='$row[pk]'>$row[name]</option>";
    }
        echo "</select>movie</br>";

    echo "<select name='actor'>";

$query = "select * from dbhx_actor";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
{
    die("query failed");
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<option value='$row[pk]'>$row[surname]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>actor</br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='swag'/>";
?>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

This is the code I have used to populate the dropdown boxes. But when I press submit, it doesn't enter the data from the chosen values. Can anyone make some sense of it?

Comment: `</form>` is missing in your code.

Comment: What does your `04castdb.php` code look like?

Comment: </form?> Where should I put it? @Sameer Mahant

Comment: It looks like this http://svn.utbildning.conduco.eu/dbhx/examples/05cast.php Though it doesn't fill up the spaces in existing casts @DevlshOne

Comment: `echo "<input type='submit' value='swag'/>";
echo "</form>";`

Comment: @Infinitewin We need to see the PHP source for `04cast.php` to resolve why the `POST`ed form values are not being submitted to the third dropdown. There are only two dropdowns on the page you have presented here.

Comment: @ Sameer Mahant, it didn't change anything.

Comment: can you post the link of your page?

Comment: @DevlshOne There isn't a third dropdown. I am trying to populate a third table using values taken from the other tables put into a third dropdown

Comment: http://kipplethomas.utbildning.conduco.eu/Kurser/Webbserverprogrammering/04castdb.php

Comment: I'm out.. I can't make heads or tails of what you actually want.

Comment: I want to be able to select two values from two populated dropdown boxes and put those related values next to each other in another table

Comment: First correct the invalid html tags in your HTML code, because  sometimes they cause problems. Change '</br>' to '<br />'

Comment: Can you see any obvious flaws in my code? And do you know how to make the code do what I want it to do?

Comment: User Firefox browser with 'HTML Validator' extention anf Firebug plugin. Once installed press 'Ctrl+U' to validate your page for HTML. You can see the errors and recommendation. Like `<form>` should not be included in `<table>` tag. Clear the errors before proceeding.

Comment: I think I have removed all of the major faults (except for those I don't understand. Did you add the tests?

Comment: Yes, I added it to check the working of page. Now tell what behavior you expect from the page.

Comment: Well, as you saw, the text inputs work. I want the swag button to enter the choices you made on the dropdown boxes to put the choices under existing casts.

Comment: You are posting the selected values to same page. Have you written the code to INSERT posted values to the third table? Then SELECT query to populate the last table in your page. If possible edit your post and add complete PHP code.

Comment: Edit my post? The first one? And how would Insert Into work with a dropdown box?